# wifi-direct peer discovery not woking in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wifip2p

I was working with the wifi-direct but its not working I can't discovery any peers I don't know whats wrong with code I'm new to android development and it never reaches **WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION** condition in **when** statement even I enabled my wifi still no peer is discovered

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
         lateinit var broadcastReciever:BroadcastReciever
         lateinit var wifip2pChannel : WifiP2pManager.Channel
          lateinit var wifip2pManager: WifiP2pManager
         lateinit var intentFilter: IntentFilter
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            wifip2pManager = this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE) as WifiP2pManager
            wifip2pChannel = wifip2pManager.initialize(this, mainLooper, null)
            intentFilter = IntentFilter()
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION)
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION)
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION)
             wifi_discover.setOnClickListener {
                 wifip2pManager.discoverPeers(wifip2pChannel,ActionListener)
                 wifi_discover.setText("discovery started")
             }
        }
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            Log.i("info","onResume")
            broadcastReciever = BroadcastReciever(wifip2pManager, wifip2pChannel, this)
            registerReceiver(broadcastReciever,intentFilter)
        }
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReciever)
        }
    class BroadcastReciever(
        val wifip2pManager: WifiP2pManager,
        var wifip2pChannel: WifiP2pManager.Channel,
        var activity:MainActivity
        ) : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val action: String = intent!!.action!!
            when (action) {
                WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
                    val state = intent!!.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1)
                    if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "wifi is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "wifi is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
                    Log.i("info","request peers")
                    wifip2pManager.requestPeers(wifip2pChannel){it ->
                        Log.i("info",it.deviceList.size.toString())
                    }
                }}}} 
    object ActionListener : WifiP2pManager.ActionListener{
        override fun onSuccess() {
            Log.i("info","success")
        }
        override fun onFailure(reason: Int) {
            if(reason == WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED){
                Log.i("info","p2p unsupported")
            }
            if(reason == WifiP2pManager.ERROR){
                Log.i("info","p2p error")
            }
            if(reason == WifiP2pManager.BUSY){
                Log.i("info","p2p b")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you added location permission and started location sharing with the application?

Comment: Yes i did still its not working

Comment: Add your code of permissions added in the manifest file

Comment: MY PERMISSION.                                        
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: your code is working fine but only one thing you need to do is that you need to give location permission manually by doing app setting -  > location - >allow all time or else you need to add location permission flow so that user can allow location 
 for the app because wifi direct needs to access location without location it will not work.

Comment: Bro already enabled still not working,can you please show me the working code?

Comment: I am not talking about enabling/disable it is about permission used by the application please read my comment again.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/a/QUqjX3d

Comment: it is same I have just run it and its working fine so no code changes are there and here you have added code to print a log of device list size so it's showing the only size.

Comment: It shows 0 as size everytime

Comment: which means you do not have any wifi direct device near you so please make sure you created another wifi direct device and you are finding that device with your application

Comment: btw who is server and who is client here? the person who send the invitation is client?

Comment: This wifi direct does not work on client-server architecture approach it works based on peer to peer connection approach but for your easiness, you can consider one which sending data is server and one which is receiving data can be a client. Same as the one which initiates connection can be a client and another one can be server